# Why does the PHP community always rely on file-based logging instead of a combination with in-memory logging?

Tags: php, logging

*This is an initial thought I'm having on logging. Clearly, am missing something about the whole picture because I don't think someone didn't think of this before.*

PHP runs on one request. That means it's contained, which means every request needs to open its own connections, etc. this is somewhat given but, when you look at how logging is done, it's somewhat infuriating: Every time an error happens, open a file, append to that file and close it, or, as far as I understand, you can open a file stream, but that still writes to the system every time logging happens.

So...why don't we just save all errors to memory, then, when the request is finished (every framework under the sun has actions, meaning that you can hook right at the end of a request), we just write these to the file?

Naturally, this has an edge-case of where the request/system for some reason critically broke down and the writing couldn't happen, but, assuming that wasn't a concern, why not just do memory-then-file writing?

Comment: What you're describing is called write-behind caching, and it is already supported by your operating system. It is simply hidden from you. In-process memory is a scarce resource under load so allocating even more of it for a cache can reduce your application's ability to scale up..

Comment: @JohnWu I understand what `write-behind caching` does on its own...I think. What I really don't get is how does this interact with a programming language / PHP? My suggestion was to put all errors in an array and at the end of a request, push them to a file instead of writing to a file constantly. Additionally, this assumption of mine "write to a file constantly" is most likely wrong. Surely PHP has something like `file streams`.

Comment: It interacts with PHP via the file system which, as John Wu pointed out, is already caching its writes in memory.

Comment: Apart from what others said. PHP also offers ways to change how errors Are handled, you can take it completly under your control. And you are forgetting one important thing, a well written application does not create any PHP level error logs.